# How to add a texture smile onto a figure?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv

[image]

Hello, So I created this Figure and want to add a smile on it but can't figure out how. I tried to use UV's but when I select everything it looks like a hot mess on the UV field, thousands of dots pressed together.. I couldnt scale the texture of the picture that way.
Then I marked areas as seem like the red lines on throat and arms, still a hot mess of dots after selection. What would be the best way to add this smile on my mesh?

Comment: Some more info might be helpful - is your goal to add a smile to this mesh as it exists, or to make this mesh into something that can be practically UV Mapped so that image texture of a smile can be used?  Because, as is, your mesh appears very high-density for UV mapping, like it's been sculpted but not retopologized or decimated yet (that's why you're getting "thousands of dots pressed together", you have thousands of vertices, far more than the shape needs).

Comment: I want to make it dance with mixamo, but just want a basic model of this figure I can customize with textures like that smile anytime I want, it's def not retopologized.. trying it rn. Does decimating work quicker?

Comment: This is the Blender Stack Exchange, Mixamo is outside of our remit.  That having been said, since their splashscreen says "Animate 3D characters for games, film, and more", topology suitable for film animation or gaming is probably needed, and that's not what you're showing.  Decimating will reduce your polycount, but won't get you "good" topology for your needs.  There's searchable info here on specific retopology issues, but for general retopology and UV unwrapping tutorials you probably want to search elsewhere, maybe YouTube or the Blender Artists forum.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a basic low-poly figure similar in shape to yours.  It wasn't sculpted, it was modeled starting from the default cube.  The topology is all-quads (although some of the poles may need to be moved for best animation, this should be sufficient for an example).  The red lines on the model are edges that have been marked as seams, which means that during unwrapping they'll be separated into different UV islands.  Because the model is low-poly with simple edge-flow, the edges can be far more easily selected and marked as seams than on a raw sculpt:

[image]

With the model UV unwrapped, an image texture (including facial features added in a 2D image editor such as [GIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP)) can be used:

[image]

[image]

In Blender the Subdivision Surface modifier can be used to simulated the appearance of a higher-poly model.  If the model is being exported to another application, either the target application's subdivision can be used (if available), or Subdivision should be Applied before export:

[image]